# How to structure SQL query to not return null for calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to do build a query that will perform the following;

1) Query a row with a given 'acctuniqueid' that has the second largest value for 'acctoutputoctets', or if no matching row is found, return 0

2) Perform the following calculation 250+350-(return value of 'acctinputoctets'+ return value of 'acctoutputoctets' || "0")

Using "a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c" as the 'acctuniqueid' field.

Table Name: radacct

### Example #1

```
+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| radacctid |           acctuniqueid           | acctinputoctets | acctoutputoctets |
+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|         5 | a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c |             150 |              250 |
|         8 | a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c |             250 |              350 |
+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

### Example #2

```
+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| radacctid |           acctuniqueid           | acctinputoctets | acctoutputoctets |
+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
|         4 | a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c |             250 |              350 |
+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

In Example #1: 250+350-(150+250) = 200
So the expected result is 200

In Example #2: 250+350-(0) = 600
So the expected result is 600

Query I've been tinkering with so far:

```
SELECT  (SUM(250)+SUM(350)-((SUM(IFNULL(acctinputoctets,0)))+
                            (SUM(IFNULL(acctoutputoctets,0))))
        )
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  *,IFNULL(acctinputoctets,0),
                    IFNULL(acctoutputoctets,0)
            FROM  radacct
            WHERE  acctuniqueid = 'a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c'
            ORDER BY  acctoutputoctets DESC
            LIMIT  1 , 1
        ) as meh
```

Which returns something for Example #1, but for Example #2 I get NULL as the result.

It should be noted that in the above query "250", "350" and "a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c" have been added manually for testing and readability purposes, but will be replaced with run-time variable output later.

I've tried various iterations, combinations and placements of IFNULL and COALESCE and have tried searching for similar problem/solution posts online - but haven't been able to find anything close enough to what I'm doing that I've had the "aha!" moment yet.

Given my (lack) of SQL experience, I'm guessing that either (a) It's something really simple that someone will spot immediately, and/or (b) I've gone about my query the completely wrong way and there is a a different and more correct way of structuring this query which is outside my current level of knowledge.

At 4AM this morning, and following hours of swearing, pleading and bargaining - I finally conceded defeat and so any assistance provided would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't the expected value of Example #2 be 0 since there is only one row and therefore you can't get the row with the second largest value for 'acctoutputoctets'? Also, when you use LIMIT 1, 1 there's no second row to return so all values would be null for Example #2.

Comment: How is a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c a useful thing to include in an example?

Comment: kaisquared - Yes, it's returning NULL but the intent is to return "0" so it can be added to the other two numbers to form a total.

Comment: Strawberry - I don't understand your question?!. The data set included is there to show an actual example of what I'm trying to match on.

Comment: I can't write a proper response now, but I'll do one when I get home tonight. Or hopefully someone else will be able to help you before then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

**Example #1**

```
CREATE TABLE radacct (
    radacctid           int,
    acctuniqueid        nvarchar(50),
    acctinputoctets     int,
    acctoutputoctets    int
    );

INSERT INTO radacct values
    (5, 'a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c', 150, 250),
    (8, 'a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c', 250, 350)


SELECT      250 + 350
            - COALESCE((SELECT acctinputoctets FROM radacct ORDER BY acctoutputoctets DESC LIMIT 1, 1), 0)
            - COALESCE((SELECT acctoutputoctets FROM radacct ORDER BY acctoutputoctets DESC LIMIT 1, 1), 0)
```

**Example #2**

```
CREATE TABLE radacct (
    radacctid           int,
    acctuniqueid        nvarchar(50),
    acctinputoctets     int,
    acctoutputoctets    int
    );

INSERT INTO radacct values
    (4, 'a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c', 250, 350);


SELECT      250 + 350
            - COALESCE((SELECT acctinputoctets FROM radacct ORDER BY acctoutputoctets LIMIT 1, 1), 0)
            - COALESCE((SELECT acctoutputoctets FROM radacct ORDER BY acctoutputoctets LIMIT 1, 1), 0)
```

However, if there are multiple rows tied for having the second largest value in acctoutputoctects, then the outcome will be quite random. For example, if in Example #1, both rows had 350 as the value in the acctoutputoctects column, then the result would depend on how the values were inserted since both rows fit the criteria, but have different values in the acctinputoctects column (which affects the answer). If you give some more information on how you want ties to be broken, I'd be happy to modify the code to accommodate it.

Comment: I considered what you were saying about two rows tired for having the second largest value, so I've now modified the structure to include an index and am now performing the ORDER BY on that instead of acctoutputoctets column.

Answer (score 0):

A major problem here is deciding in the case of draws which acctinputoctets to pick. This nasty looking code trys to pick the most recent highest and second highest values based on radacctid before left joining to get the final result

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t( radacctid int,           acctuniqueid  varchar(40), acctinputoctets int, acctoutputoctets int);
insert into t values
(         5 , 'a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c' ,             150 ,              250), 
(         8 , 'a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c' ,             250 ,              350), 
(         9 , 'a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c' ,             200 ,              250), 
(         4 , 'b25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c' ,             10 ,                10),
(         6 , 'b25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c' ,             250 ,              350),
(            7 , 'c25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c' ,             20 ,                30); 

select mm.acctuniqueid,mm.maxid,mm.maxin,mm.maxout ,
         sm.acctuniqueid,sm.secondmaxid,sm.secondmaxin,sm.secondmaxout,
         (ifnull(mm.maxin,0) + ifnull(mm.maxout,0)) - 
         (ifnull(sm.secondmaxin,0) + ifnull(sm.secondmaxout,0)) as Total
from
(
select t.acctuniqueid,t.radacctid maxid,t.acctinputoctets maxin,t.acctoutputoctets maxout  
from t
join
(
select t.acctuniqueid,s.maxout, max(radacctid) maxid   #adjust maxid as required
from
(
select acctuniqueid, max(acctoutputoctets) maxout
from t 
where acctoutputoctets = (select max(acctoutputoctets) from t t1 where t1.acctuniqueid = t.acctuniqueid)
group by acctuniqueid
) s
join t on t.acctuniqueid = s.acctuniqueid and t.acctoutputoctets = s.maxout
group by t.acctuniqueid,s.maxout
) s
on s.acctuniqueid = t.acctuniqueid and s.maxid = t.radacctid
) mm
left join
(
select t.acctuniqueid,t.radacctid secondmaxid,t.acctinputoctets secondmaxin,t.acctoutputoctets secondmaxout  
from t
join
(
select t.acctuniqueid,s.secondmaxout, max(radacctid) secondmaxid   #adjust secondmaxid as required
from
(
select acctuniqueid, max(acctoutputoctets) secondmaxout
from t 
where acctoutputoctets < (select max(acctoutputoctets) from t t1 where t1.acctuniqueid = t.acctuniqueid)
group by acctuniqueid
) s
join t on t.acctuniqueid = s.acctuniqueid and t.acctoutputoctets = secondmaxout
group by t.acctuniqueid,s.secondmaxout
) s
on s.acctuniqueid = t.acctuniqueid and s.secondmaxid = t.radacctid
) sm
on mm.acctuniqueid = sm.acctuniqueid

+----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------+
| acctuniqueid                     | maxid | maxin | maxout | acctuniqueid                     | secondmaxid | secondmaxin | secondmaxout | Total |
+----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------+
| a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c |     8 |   250 |    350 | a25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c |           9 |         200 |          250 |   150 |
| b25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c |     6 |   250 |    350 | b25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c |           4 |          10 |           10 |   580 |
| c25d16693309cdb4807effe00a9f076c |     7 |    20 |     30 | NULL                             |        NULL |        NULL |         NULL |    50 |
+----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Possibly could be simplified if you simply needed the max (or min) in value to go with the max out value in the event of a draw.